# gridview in bootstrap modal popup issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I used bootstrap modal popup and in that there is need to implement a gridview.
Using update panel,I added gridview and databinding is working properly.
In gridview row, there is a textbox where user can modify the existing values and update with a save button outside the gridview.

But when I fire the Save button command at server side, I am not getting the updated values instead I am getting old values by looping gridview rows controls.

How to get the updated values of from textbox in gridview inside bootstrap modal popup? I have used update panel also.

Please suggest.

Comment: show your save button event and gridview markup

Answer (score 0):

In save button event, make sure that you are refreshing the gridview content adding  databind() once you have saved the new values

```
YourGridView.DataSource = TheSource;
YourGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

after hitting the update and fetching back the updated values you should register back the modal popup from c# at the end of the same event

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"Pop", "openModal();", true);``
```

Customize the script according to your need